# Mysql - deleting second entry

Tags: mysql

We have a mysql database table that has some erroneous entries that need to be removed. The account table has the following fields: id, code, user_id

Basically, each user should only have one record in the account table for each account. However, at the moment, each user has two records in the account table where the code is equal to 1000.

For every record in the account table, I need to remove the second row where the code = 1000 for each user.

The following query give me all records where the code = 1000. It also contains a count on the account_detail table to confirm that the second erroneous entry does not contain any child records in the account_detail table, and this has been confirmed as correct.

```
SELECT a.*, COUNT(ad.id)
FROM account a
LEFT JOIN account_detail ad on a.id = ad.account_id
WHERE a.code = 1000
GROUP by a.id
ORDER BY a.user_id, a.id
```

So, now I basically need a query that will delete the second erroneous entry for each user_id in the account table where code = 1000

Comment: It would be better if you posted some sample data from the 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE greater
FROM   account AS lower JOIN account AS greater
    ON lower.code    = greater.code
   AND lower.user_id = greater.user_id
   AND lower.id      < greater.id
WHERE  lower.code    = 1000
```

Comment: Nope, wont work. We need to retain the first entry for every user in account table where code = 1000, even if ad.account_id IS NULL

Comment: @JonoB: if `ad.account_id IS NULL` also for the first record then there's no corresponding entry in `account_detail` for *either* record, correct?  In that case, how do you determine which is the "first" and which is the "second" record?

Comment: the query in the OP has an order by clause: `ORDER BY a.user_id, a.id, so the second a.id will always be larger than the first. I've pretty much solved this though, by using my first query, and then looping over the results in php and extracting the id for each of the second accounts. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @JonoB:  Fair enough.  Or alternatively use my revised answer above.